# Extracting month using substring in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code

```
@FiscalMonth  As varchar(MAX) ='[Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Number].&[10]&[2014]&[4]&[1]'
```

In my case the month will be `10` . I have tried the following code

```
SET @FiscalMonthNumber = cast(substring(right(@FiscalMonth,18),1,2) as nvarchar(max))
```

The code above works fine but when I have

```
@FiscalMonth  As varchar(MAX) ='[Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Number].&[10]&[2014]&[11]&[1]'
```

I have as result   `0]` which is incorrect .

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have an hierarchy of date and I would like to extract the month which is according to the example above 10 .

Comment: What is a "hierarchy of date"?

Comment: Why are you casting as nvarchar?

Comment: You're using tsql to build mdx?

Comment: @billinkc yes I'm using tsql to build mdx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh. This assumes that the first time you encounter a pattern like `'[n'` (where `n` is any number, and it will occur within the first 8000 characters of the string), that is the month:

```
DECLARE @fm VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @fm = '[Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Number].&[10]&[2014]&[4]&[1]';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@fm, PATINDEX('%[[][0-9]%', @fm) + 1, 
  CHARINDEX(']', SUBSTRING(@fm, PATINDEX('%[[][0-9]%', @fm) + 1, 8000)) - 1);
```

Result:

```
----------
10
```

If there are other possible patterns or edge cases, make them known.

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc850/1)

Comment: [Updated SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a20e7/1) for the edit (though my solution doesn't rely on `RIGHT()`).

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code it is working fine it is showing 10 in both cases maybe you need to look into you logic.

DECLARE @FiscalMonth  varchar(MAX) ='[Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Number].&[10]&[2014]&[4]&[1]'

DECLARE @FiscalMonthNumber nvarchar(max) = cast(substring(right(@FiscalMonth,18),1,2) as nvarchar(max))

SELECT  @FiscalMonthNumber

DECLARE @FiscalMonth1  As varchar(MAX) ='[Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Number].&[10]&[2014]&[4]&[1]'

DECLARE @FiscalMonthNumber1 AS nvarchar(max) = cast(substring(right(@FiscalMonth,18),1,2) as nvarchar(max))

SELECT @FiscalMonthNumber1

Comment: In the second case I have @FiscalMonth  As varchar(MAX) ='[Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Number].&[10]&[2014]&[11]&[1]'

Comment: Or you can extract all the numbers from you string and then extract the month number from your number string. something like this

Comment: Good idea , I 'll try to implement it .

Answer (score 0):

Or you can extract all the numbers from you string and then extract the month number from your number string. something like this

DECLARE @FiscalMonth1  As varchar(MAX) ='[Dim Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Month Number].&[10]&[2014]&[4]&[1]'

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@FiscalMonth1) <> 0

SET @FiscalMonth1 = STUFF(@FiscalMonth1,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@FiscalMonth1),1,'')

SELECT LEFT(@FiscalMonth1, 2)

Comment: try this code. this as it is gives you result 10 but again then you can change it if you have more number in the start other then just you month